# Sapu Lidi: A broom made of many wooden sticks

Tags: word-choice, british-english, translation

For many Indonesians, the name *sapu lidih* or *sapu lidi* is somewhat familiar. Well, this "sapu lidih" is actually a broom made of many wooden sticks. If you translate the name directly to English, it will be broomsticks. However, broomsticks give an impression of Harry Potter with his witch broom that he used to fly around. The *sapu lidih* does not look like it at all. Its sticks are made from dried coconut leaves and there is a whole bunch of them bundled them together to form a broom.

We use this broom to clean our beds. We use it to sweep the dust or other debris on our bed to the floor. So what is this type of broom called and what is the action of sweeping the bed using the sapu lidih called in English?

Answer (score 6):

I know the thing you mean, thanks to spending four and a half years in Indonesia, and I called it a [besom broom](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=sapu+lidi&hl=en&pwst=1&prmd=imvns&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=UIGLUPykKISzrAe_oIHoDA&ved=0CEwQsAQ&biw=1280&bih=618#hl=en&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=besom+broom&oq=besom&gs_l=img.1.2.0l3j0i5l3j0i24l4.82421.83929.0.88416.5.5.0.0.0.0.143.377.4j1.5.0...0.0...1c.1.KoRmxv9eRxA&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=40a17cc3bf2a0d58&bpcl=35466521&biw=1280&bih=618)

Coleoptorist's coconut broom looks to be the same object, but I have to say I had never heard that name before today.

Looking at Ngram because it is quick and easy, using 'English' [to compare coconut broom with besom broom](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=besom+broom%2Ccoconut+broom&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) shows them both in use, but using [British English](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=besom+broom%2Ccoconut+broom&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=) or [American English](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=besom+broom%2Ccoconut+broom&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=) shows only besom broom.

Now I am intrigued...

Comment: I'd thought of _besom_, but in the UK they're used in the garden.

Comment: Are they still _besom brooms_ sans the handle/pole that the OP wants to avoid? That said, some of the _sapu lidi_ pics show handles as do the _coconut broom_ pics; but they tend to be really short when present.

Comment: Yes, in the UK it is an outdoor brush, and usually has a handle and a head. In Indonesia (actually, most of Asia) sapu lidih they are used in the house, in the garden, in the street, everywhere, with or without a handle. Simple, cheap, biodegradable - they are wonderful things!

Comment: @coleopterist ~ [this one has no handle](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/6-Cinnamon-Besom-Broom-Altars-Ceremonial-Use-/290587469904) In Bahasa Indonesi, it is sapu lidih whether it has a handle or not.

Comment: I see. _That_ reminds me of a _fly-whisk_ :| +1 for local knowledge :)

Comment: In contrast to what you said, Roaring Fish, I've heard the term _coconut broom_ before, but _besom broom_ is new to me.  Interesting.

Comment: I am a native Indonesian. I should say that **Sapu lidi is not a besom broom**. I am posting the pictures of **Sapu lidi** with its various utility, may it help! :) Pics courtesy: Google [Image 1](http://i.stack.imgur.com/3jOfl.jpg),[image 2](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hnsgd.jpg),[image 3](http://i.stack.imgur.com/VFKju.jpg),[image 4](http://i.stack.imgur.com/iH93v.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

They're called [coconut brooms](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22coconut%20broom%22). While you'd *sweep* the floors with it, you're more likely to *brush* your beds clean.